# How to limit the amount of time SCP tries to connect for?

Tags: networking, bash, ssh

I have a bash script which copies any files in a 'to_send' directory, to a remote server via `scp`. The script runs an `scp` command on each file, checks the return code, and moves the local version from the to_send directory to a 'sent' directory if successful. If unsuccessful the file stays in the 'to_send' directory, ready to attempt sending the next time the script is run.

The `scp` uses a URL and non standard port number to send via an internet connection. I have an issue whereby, if the connection to the remote server is not possible, each instance of the `scp` command takes about two minutes to determine that it cannot connect. This is not a terrible overhead if there's only one file to send, but will cause problems if there are several files to send.

Is there a way to limit how long the attempt to connect will continue trying for? Perhaps by passing an option to `ssh` with the `-o` option of `scp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass along SSH options, like `-o ConnectTimeout=10` to timeout after 10 seconds.

But if you're copying multiple files, `rsync` might be worth looking at. And you'd probably use `--contimeout 10` for an `rsync` command.

Comment: Thanks, I use `rsync` a fair bit, but don't have a handle on how I'd get it to check that a file has been successfully sent, then move that file locally, and log what had happened in a format of my choosing. Perhaps using the `--remove-source-files` option, then somehow making those deleted source files backup. Though I can't find an option for that. I suppose that's another question entirely though. The whole connection time limiting thing is a bit of an edge case in my situation, but I just like to tie up as many foreseen problems as possible, then wait for the unforeseen ones to start!

Comment: I might be tempted to transfer all the files with rsync and pipe its output (a list of copied files) back into a new ssh command that did the move. Not sure if that is safe, but it's an interesting idea and a much lower connection overhead.